# Regions in Croogo

Tags: croogo

I'm having some problems in displaying elements in different regions.

After installing and using Croogo for a while, I made several trials
adding custom elements and custom menus.  If I choose region
'right' (being the default region for elements used by Croogo once
installed) everything is fine and I'm able to add anything I want
without any problem.

Anyhow when I choose any other region to display my element (header,
footer, left) nothing is displayed (looking at the source of the page
I noticed the element is not even rendered).
Am I missing something? How can I actually use different regions to
display elements/blocks?

I'm also a bit confused about the 9 regions (named regionX with
X=[1,..,9]) available along with header, footer, left, right. What's
their purpose? Do they actually represent a region on the screen or
they have been left not configured?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to adjust your theme.json so that the desired regions is loaded.